Problems while calling the API: The authManager is: null; the authCallback is: null; the mContext is: null
In my project, I want to call a Baidu map API (a Chinese map API), I wrote MapApp.java for this program, initialized the SDK in this file, and also declared it as the entry point of the program in manifest.xml. And I wrote a MapActivity.java file to call this API, but when I run it, Logcat shows The authManager is: null; the authCallback is: null; the mContext is: null. I'm a newcomer to programming, so I'd like to ask What should I do to call this API successfully?
this is the error information
This is my MapApp.java
I have also declared location permissions, network permissions and other related permissions in the manifest file.
Thank you all very much! If more error messages are needed to solve the problem please ask me directly! Thanks!
I've checked the initialization of the authorization manager with context passing as per Chatgpt's tip, which is my MapApp.java file, and I personally can't find a problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
